# Sort algorithm for "weak order"?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, quadratic

I have unordered elements in a vector. There's no transitivity; if element A > B and B > C, A > C doesn't need to be true.

I need to sort them so that an element is greater than its following one.

For example, if we have three elements A, B and C, and:

```
A<B, A>C
B<C, B>A
C<A, C>B
```

and the vector is `<A,B,C>`, we would need to sort it as `<A,C,B>`.

I've done the sorting with bubble sort and other classic sorting algorithms that require O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, but doesn't look efficient.

Is there a more efficient algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: You can only sort according to an order, and what you are describing isn't one.

Comment: Is it possible that A>B, B>C, C>A (ot similar with more elements)?

Comment: In the question you state that you've solved this problem using "bubble sort and other classic sorting algorithms." But those algorithms just don't work here because your `<` relation is effectively an arbitrary relation and not any sort of order, weak or otherwise. The problem is equivalent to finding a Hamiltonian path, for which no known polynomial-time algorithms exist. See my answer.

Comment: This is non-transitive sorting. Should not be downvoted. A legit question, and I'm here as I have the same one.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your data as a graph, where the elements of your array `A`, `B`, `C` are vertices, and a (directed) edge between two vertices `x` and `y` are comparisons `x>y`.

The requirement to order the elements such that each adjacent pair `x`, `y` satisfies `x>y` is, in the graph view of your problem, the same as finding a Hamiltonian path through the vertices.

There's no apparent restrictions for your `>` relation (for example, it's not transitive, and it's ok for it to contain cycles), so the graph you get is an arbitrary graph. So you're left with the problem of finding a Hamiltonian path in an arbitrary graph, which is an NP complete problem. That means you're not going to find an easy, efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

What are you seeking is called [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: It is; numbers are *nodes*, each *>* is a directed *edge*. So in the eaxmple above we have `A`, `B`, `C` nodes and `A->B` and `B->C` edges

Comment: I note in the example given, there's a cycle A<B<C<A, which means it doesn't satisfy the conditions to a weak order which toposort requires. There's another problem too -- Toposort finds an order such if x precedes y then not(y<x). But the question asks for something different: that if y immediately follows x then x>y. (At least, as I understand the question as written).

Comment: In what example? There are no examples in my answer.

Comment: The example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Quicksort. I choose a pivot element, and sort elements so that I have two halves: elements lesser than the pivot and elements greater than the pivot. Quicksort is executed again recursively for those two halves. That way I have a O(*n*log *n*) complexity time on average.

Thanks for the comments!